# Safely ignoring the `problems` attribute of the `readr::spec_tbl_df` tibble subclass for the purpose of testing the equality of data stored in tibbles

Tags: r, readr

I'm interested in testing the equality of tibbles read in with `readr::read_csv()`.

If the only difference between two such tibbles is the pointer value stored in the otherwise empty `problems` attribute of these tibbles, the tibbles are for my purposes identical.

How would you recommend that I establish that two such tibbles are identical other than these differing pointers stored in the problems attributes?

```
library(tidyverse)

tibble(
  x = 1:3
) %>%
  write_csv(file = '~/Documents/demo.csv')

d1.tb <- read_csv(file = '~/Documents/demo.csv')

d2.tb <- read_csv(file = '~/Documents/demo.csv')

identical(d1.tb, d2.tb)
[1] FALSE
```

I've seen square bracket subsetting used to remove the additional attributes of the `spec_tbl_df` subclass.

```
identical(d1.tb[], d2.tb[])
[1] TRUE
```

Or should I be avoiding `identical()` and using `all.equal()` instead?

```
all.equal(d1.tb, d2.tb)
[1] TRUE
```

Thank you for your time.

---

Additional code demonstrating that the two tibbles differ only in the pointer stored in the 'problems' attribute:

```
identical(attributes(d1.tb), attributes(d2.tb))
[1] FALSE
problems(d1.tb)
# A tibble: 0 × 5
# … with 5 variables: row <int>, col <int>, expected <chr>, actual <chr>,
#   file <chr>
problems(d2.tb)
# A tibble: 0 × 5
# … with 5 variables: row <int>, col <int>, expected <chr>, actual <chr>,
#   file <chr>
 identical(attributes(d1.tb)$problems, attributes(d2.tb)$problems)
[1] FALSE
```

```
d1.1.tb <- d1.tb
d2.1.tb <- d2.tb
attributes(d1.1.tb)$problems <- 'overwritten by user'
attributes(d2.1.tb)$problems <- 'overwritten by user'
identical(d1.1.tb, d2.1.tb)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/702) for the readxl vignette that's touches on the problem of determining equality between data frames that have different attributes, but are otherwise the same. Hopefully the package developers get back to me with an answer that could help you as well!

Comment: Thank you for reaching out, I will monitor the progress of your GitHub Issue with interest. Incidentally, have you seen that `dplyr::all_equal` is being deprecated? https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/pull/6349

Comment: I did not! I'll update my question to include this, thanks :)